# Neo4J POJO approach

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I have a quick question for Neo4J, is it possible to migrate from mysql to neo4j? Based from what I read, it seems that you can, but so far all the tutorials are meant for web service. I was wondering if there is a way (POJO) to do this kind of process. Currently I have over 300k records in process to be exported in CSV and I plan to load them into neo4j using spring. Can I just read them with JDBC and create new nodes in neo4j? thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe it more what you mean by POJO approach?

Comment: @MicTech I'm sorry if I wasnt quite clear. What I'm facing right now is this spring app becomes like a rest-app. my intention wasnt to create that but rather a standalone java - neo4j DB interface

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to migrate MySQL database to Neo4j, but it depends how you want to do it and what results do you expect.

You can use CSV export/import. It's simple to use, but with some limitations. For one time operation it should be good enough.

Second option is to write your own script or program which transform data from RDBMS to the Graph. It could be more powerful, you can do cleaning, transformation easily. Also you can use Spring Data for Neo4j to create persisted entities.

Next option is to use [GraphAware Neo4j Importer](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-importer). It's "Framework" for importing data from RDBMS to the Neo4j with lot of powerful features, but learning curve is steep.

Comment: is it possible to run neo4j without REST?